# how to know what values are sending from my Activity to MySql server in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

i am using Volley to send data to MySQL. i don't know why my data is not inserting in to MySQL, i want to see that data which is sending from Activity to MySQL server. bellow is my code

```
private void SendDatatoserver(final String name,final String bname,final String location,final String phone,
              final String website,final String disc,final String ownerphone,final String gname,final String latlong, final String spinner)
    {

        String tag_string_req = "req_vend_reg";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppURLs.Vend_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hideDialog();
                //Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    if (!error) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AddNewBusiness.this, SuccessBsub.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "vregister");
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("bname", bname);
                params.put("address", location);
                params.put("phoneno", phone);
                params.put("website", website);
                params.put("disc", disc);
                params.put("ownerphone", ownerphone);
                params.put("gname", gname);
                params.put("latlong", latlong);
                params.put("spinner", spinner);
                return params;
            }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

i am using `PHP` to insert the data into MySQL.

my PHP Code

```
 if($tag == 'vregister'){

            $vname =$_POST['name'];
            $bname =$_POST['bname'];
            $vaddress =$_POST['address'];
            $vphoneno =$_POST['phoneno'];
            $vwebsite =$_POST['website'];
            $vdisc =$_POST['disc'];
            $vownerphone =$_POST['ownerphone'];
            $vgname =$_POST['gname'];
            $vlatlong =$_POST['latlong'];
            $vspinner =$_POST['spinner'];

            $status='Pending';


            //insert and get response
            $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `newvenderreq`(pname, bname, address, phone, website, ownerphone, disc, gname, latlng, date, status, spinner) VALUES (:pname, :bname, :address, :phone, :website, :ownerphone, :disc, :gname, :latlng, NOW(), :status, :spinner)");
            $sql->execute(array(':pname'=>$vname,
                                ':bname'=>$bname,
                                ':address'=>$vaddress,
                                ':phone'=>$vphoneno,
                                ':website'=>$vwebsite,
                                ':ownerphone'=>$vownerphone,
                                ':disc'=>$vdisc,
                                ':gname'=>$vgname,
                                ':latlng'=>$vlatlong,
                                ':status'=>$status,
                                ':spinner'=>$vspinner ));

            if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                //$response["uid"] = $user["id"];
                //$response["bname"]= $bname;

                header('Content-Type:Application/json');
                $array[] = $response;
                echo json_encode($array);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }

        }
```

Comment: there's no php here only Android code. and TBH, am not even sure there is MySQL code in the question.

Comment: what is the server response

Comment: i am getting message Error occured in Registartion

Comment: i added my php code

Comment: Without adding, inserting condition just `echo $vname` that will print name as output.

Comment: And also first you have to connect to database in php  server code.

Comment: i am sorry, those who are not understand my question, i am using volley to send data , and php to inset the data in to mysql. but due to some reason its not inseting. i want to is there any possibility to check in android studio. what data is sending to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP code just remove this line

```
$array[] = $response;
```

pass $response in `json_encode($response);`